# Diseñar una función es_repeticion en python 3

Tags: python-3.x, funciones

tengo una duda con respecto a un ejercicio con Python y es la siguiente:

1. Me pide diseñar una función que se llame es_repeticion que reciba una cadena y nos diga si la cadena esta formada mediante la concatenación de una cadena consigo misma. Por ejemplo, es_repeticion('abab') devolverá TRUE, pues la cadena 'abab' esta formada con la cadena 'ab' repetida; por contra es_repeticion('ababab') devolverá FALSE.

Adjunto un pantallazo de mi código. Pero, cabe destacar que si bien el ejercicio funciona, pero solo si hay letras repetidas, mas no palabras. Ejemplo: Si en mi código ingreso holahola, me devolverá TRUE, pero si ingreso hola devolverá FALSE. En que he fallado? ¿Qué es lo que falta?

Saludos de un programador novato en Python.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `return cadena[:len(cadena) // 2] == cadena[len(cadena) // 2:]`

Comment: Muchas gracias.  Saludos.

Comment: usa el codigo del comentario como respuesta a tu pregunta y marca como cerrada.